# How to fill data into TableLayout using BaseAdapter?

Tags: android, android-layout, fragment, tablelayout, android-tablelayout

I am trying to make an application in android where i'll have two sets of data. I've have to show headers on top of each dataset.
So I chose tableLayout show the output of the data. I need to fill 5 cells in each row.
For Example:

```
*Header1*  
dataSet1.1  dataSet1.2  dataSet1.3  dataSet1.4  dataSet1.5  
dataSet1.1  dataSet1.2  dataSet1.3  dataSet1.4  dataSet1.5  
dataSet1.1  dataSet1.2  dataSet1.3  dataSet1.4  dataSet1.5  
dataSet1.1  dataSet1.2  dataSet1.3  dataSet1.4  dataSet1.5  

*Header2*  
dataSet2.1  dataSet2.2  dataSet2.3  dataSet2.4  dataSet2.5  
dataSet2.1  dataSet2.2  dataSet2.3  dataSet2.4  dataSet2.5  
dataSet2.1  dataSet2.2  dataSet2.3  dataSet2.4  dataSet2.5  
dataSet2.1  dataSet2.2  dataSet2.3  dataSet2.4  dataSet2.5
```

I am able to fill the data but when the device is small, only half of the row's visible and rest of row is getting clipped. I mean, from the row,  only dataSet1.1, dataSet1.2 and half of dataSet1.3 is shown and rest of them are getting clipped. Same is happening for every row.
Below is my code.
Fragment(Java):

```
public class VideoFragment  extends Fragment implements VideoFragmentView
{
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS = 5;
    private static final long REFRESH_TIMEOUT_MINUTES = 15;

    private static final int NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS = 4;
    private static final long REFRESH_TIMEOUT_MINUTES = 15;

    private GuideMediaItemAdapter guideMediaItemAdapter;
    TableLayout mainTable;

    private LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager;

    public static VideoFragment newInstance()
    {
        VideoFragment fragment = new VideoFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void toLoadingState()
    {
        // No - Op
    }

    @Override
    public void toLoadedState()
    {
        // No - Op
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        DaggerVideoFragmentComponent.builder()
            .applicationComponent(((PhoenixApp) getContext().getApplicationContext()).getComponent())
            .videoFragmentModule(new VideoFragmentModule(this))
            .build()
            .inject(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nav_video_content_table_view, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext());

        getPresenter().start();

        /**
        * TODO : Add below given two for loops into one.
         */
        mainTable = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.displayLinear);

        TableRow guideHeaderRow = new TableRow(getContext());
        View guideHeaderView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.guide_header_nav_item, null);
        guideHeaderRow.addView(guideHeaderView);
        mainTable.addView(guideHeaderRow);
        TableRow falseRow1 = new TableRow(getContext());
        falseRow1.setMinimumHeight(10);
        mainTable.addView(falseRow1);

        for (int i = 0; i < guideMediaItemAdapter.getCount(); i++)
        {
            TableRow row = new TableRow(getContext());
            for (int j = 0; j < 4 && i < guideMediaItemAdapter.getCount(); j++)
            {
                int tmp = i++;
                View viewToAdd = guideMediaItemAdapter.getView(tmp, null, null);
                Entity entity = (Entity) guideMediaItemAdapter.getItem(tmp);
                row.addView(viewToAdd);
                if (j == 3)
                {
                    i--;
                    mainTable.addView(row);
                }
            }
        }
        mainTable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void setGridAdapter(BaseNavContentFragment.MediaItemAdapter adapter)
    {
        // No - Op. Do not set any general adapter.
    }

    @Override
    public void setGuideGridAdapter(GuideMediaItemAdapter adapter)
    {
        guideMediaItemAdapter = adapter;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        getPresenter().stop();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public static class GuideMediaItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {

        private static String LOGTAG = "GuideMediaItemAdapter";
        private final List<Entity> items;
        private final LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        private final int firstLastRowPadding;
        private final int stationMargins;
        private final Context mContext;

        public GuideMediaItemAdapter(Context context, List<Entity> items)
        {
            this.mContext = context;
            this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.items = items;
            firstLastRowPadding = ViewUtil.convertDpToPx(context, 16);
            stationMargins = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.radio_logo_tile_inset);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return items.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position)
        {
            return items.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position)
        {
            return items.get(position).id.hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View itemView;

            // fetch the item from the list/grid.
            Entity entity = items.get(position);

            if (convertView == null)
            {
                itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_item, null);
            }
            else
            {
                itemView = convertView;
            }

            ImageView titleIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleIcon);
            if (entity instanceof Station)
            {
                titleIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_radio_small);
                titleIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else if (entity instanceof Ad && !((Ad) entity).isArtist)
            {
                titleIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_ad_mcdonalds);
                titleIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {
                titleIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            TextView titleTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            titleTextView.setText(entity.title);
            titleTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            TextView subtitleView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(entity.subtitle))
            {
                subtitleView.setText(entity.subtitle);
                subtitleView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {
                subtitleView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            TextView badgeStandardAd = itemView.findViewById(R.id.badgeStandardAd);
            badgeStandardAd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            TextView badge = itemView.findViewById(R.id.badge);
            badge.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ImageView imageOverlayView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageOverlay);
            imageOverlayView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (entity instanceof Ad && ((Ad) entity).isArtist)
            {
                badge.setText(R.string.sponsored_artist);
                badge.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            if (entity instanceof Station && ((Station) entity).isProgram)
            {
                Station station = (Station) entity;
                badge.setText(station.startTime + " - " + station.endTime);
                badge.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            ImageView artView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            artView.setImageResource(R.drawable.album_art_placeholder);
            artView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            if (entity instanceof Station && !((Station) entity).isProgram)
            {
                ViewUtil.setMargins(imageOverlayView, stationMargins);
                ViewUtil.setMargins(artView, stationMargins);
            }
            else
            {
                ViewUtil.setMargins(imageOverlayView, 0);
                ViewUtil.setMargins(artView, 0);
            }

            int lastRowNumberOfItems = getCount() % NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS;
            if (lastRowNumberOfItems == 0)
            {
                lastRowNumberOfItems = 5;
            }

            if (position < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS)
            {
                //top first row
                itemView.setPadding(0, firstLastRowPadding, 0, 0);
            }
            else if (position >= getCount() - lastRowNumberOfItems)
            {
                //bottom last row
                itemView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, firstLastRowPadding);
            }
            else
            {
                itemView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            }

            return itemView;
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment(layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp">

        <TableLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/displayLinear"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center">

        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

nav_item (layout which creates each item of the row):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/imageContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/nav_item_background"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageOverlay"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="#b4ffffff"
                android:scaleType="centerInside" />
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/badge"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:background="#ccffffff"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:text="@string/sponsored_artist"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    tools:visibility="visible"
                    android:paddingTop="6dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
                    android:paddingStart="6dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="6dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/lato_regular"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/badgeStandardAd"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:background="#046c4f"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    tools:text="Exit 29"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    tools:visibility="gone"
                    android:paddingTop="6dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
                    android:paddingStart="6dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="6dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/lato_regular"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/titleContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageContainer"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/titleIcon"
            android:layout_width="22dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
            android:lines="1"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/titleContainer"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/lato_regular"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        android:textColor="#63666a"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

There are a lot of questions on stackOverflow but most of them are for static tables and i've tried most of them it made the table scrollable but row are getting overflowed from view is the problem here which i am not able to fix.
Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 1):

I found what i was doing wrong. I was not setting the layoutParams for each cell in the row. Adding proper layoutParam for each cell solves the problem.
Below is the code changes i did:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext());

    getPresenter().start();

    /**
    * TODO : Add below given two for loops into one.
     */
    mainTable = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.displayLinear);

    TableRow guideHeaderRow = new TableRow(getContext());
    View guideHeaderView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.guide_header_nav_item, null);
    guideHeaderRow.addView(guideHeaderView);
    mainTable.addView(guideHeaderRow);
    TableRow falseRow1 = new TableRow(getContext());
    falseRow1.setMinimumHeight(10);
    mainTable.addView(falseRow1);

    for (int i = 0; i < guideMediaItemAdapter.getCount(); i++)
    {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(getContext());
        for (int j = 0; j < 4 && i < guideMediaItemAdapter.getCount(); j++)
        {
            int tmp = i++;
            View viewToAdd = guideMediaItemAdapter.getView(tmp, null, null);

            // Adding these two lines will solve the problem
            TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);
            viewToAdd.setLayoutParams(params);
            // -------------
            Entity entity = (Entity) guideMediaItemAdapter.getItem(tmp);
            row.addView(viewToAdd);
            if (j == 3)
            {
                i--;
                mainTable.addView(row);
            }
        }
    }
    mainTable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach to your problem is not a good one maybe that's why you might be having view clipping issues.You are creating views dynamically based on the quantity of items in your data set. You can use Android's GridView or a RecyclerView for handling a list with a Spacing decoration and a GridLayoutManager which takes a primary constructor parameter of spanCount which is the number of columns required for your grid and then you will need to create your own extension of Recycler.Adapter to attach with RecyclerView and also as many needed extensions of RecyclerView.ViewHolder class which represent view type of your data individually. 1st one is a good solution but the 2nd is recommended one as per Android guidelines [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview).It will provide you precise control over the list being handled. For different types of data views in your list you can override getItemViewType method of the extended adapter class to differentiate between headers,footers and content of your listing and if you do not want your list to be scrollable you can disable scroll on a RecyclerView as well.This will hopefully solve your problem.

Comment: I tried gridView and it works very well for one data set. but as i said, i have two data set and i have to set header before each dataset.
sample of my view will be:  


  
*Header1*  
dataSet1.1  dataSet1.2 . dataSet1.3 dataSet1.4 dataSet1.5  
...  
...  
...  

*Header 2*  
dataSet2.1  dataSet1.2 . dataSet2.3 dataSet2.4 dataSet2.5  
...  
...  
...  

This was un-achievable by using gridView and RecyclerView also does not look a good example to me.

Comment: RecyclerView clearly works for you you just don't know how to do it yet. Its simple you want header1 content1,content2,content3, header2 content1 content2 content3 I have given clear answer on exactly how this can be done by RecyclerView you still have to do it yourself. Also you need to put another recyclerview inside your row layout for a separate listing there you go the answer you were looking for.

Comment: can you please give an example? I am sorry if i am asking for much.

Comment: Also you didn't mention this problem in your question. See your comment and question they are 2 different problems.

Comment: I am sorry if i created a confusion for you.

Comment: Hey upvote my answer and use this link to below to clone my project. https://bitbucket.org/mmobin789/scouts-aj2019
You can find your solution in the 'activities named activity'

Comment: I still do not see how i am supposed to add multiple cells in a single item of recycler view.

Comment: You need to search through the project if you can't understand code I can't help you through it. Good luck.